# Cucumber cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber

I created a RunTest class to run my test scenarios using Cucumber with JUnit. To run the tests before, I need to import into my project the RunWith class (@RunWith) and pass as parameter the Cucumber.class. Then, the RunWith parameter of the class recognizes more of the parameter that is passed to it, no.
The eclipse displays the message:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - Class  can not be resolved to a type.
>   - Cucumber can not be resolved to a type.
>   - The annotation @RunWith must define the attribute value

I'm using Maven to organize my JARS files.
Following is the code and error screens.

[image]
[image]

My POM.XML

> 

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My Libraries
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to import Cucumber ?

Comment: Indeed, try adding `import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;` .

Comment: Yes. I've tried but the eclipse displays the message: The import cucumber.junit can not be resolved.
I think I'm missing some JAR file in my project.

Comment: See if this helps : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_java_testing.htm

Comment: In your `pom.xml` you have the dependency `info.cukes:cucumber-jvm:pom:1.2.5` which is not in the list of dependencies on any of your screenshots. What happen if you run `mvn compile` on command line? I created a small project with your `pom.xml` and `RunTest.java` and it compiles just ok.

Comment: I added cucumber-jvm dependency but it still did not work. Eclipse now displays the error message:
java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException: org.junit.runner.RunWith missing element value

Answer (score 12):

I also faced the same issue in IntelliJ idea, When I check in the imported libraries it was like below screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

So I remove scope tag from my import in pom file.Then it worked.

**Earlier**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Fix**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it is working fine

Answer (score 9):

Import the `cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber` class. It seems you are using Eclipse IDE, so you can import the classes using the `Ctrl+Shift+o` (alphabet 'o' not zero) shortcut.

(`Ctrl+Shift+O` is 'Organise Imports', and will add any missing imports, remove any unused ones, and order all of your imports). The command is also found under Source > Organise Imports.

Comment: Go to Project Properties->Java Build Path. In Libraries tab check if "cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar" is in Maven Dependencies. If not then add it.

Comment: Hello nikhil Ingole. The dependency was already added. I updated my question with the image of dependency. Look above.

Comment: Hi Kakashi, I think you are missing some dependent jars. Check "Option 3" at http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/download-cucumber-jvm-eclipse/

Comment: It did the magic for me!

Comment: It also did magic to me. Ctrl+Shift+O

Answer (score 1):

Just do Ctrl+Shift+T and type RunWith check if the jar is correctly imported into your work space after maven dependencies are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I removed my POM.xml file from the dependency below:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And I added the dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Done that I was able to do import.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Mouse hovering on error shows, class cucumber cannot be resolved to a type.
  so, write the import statement manually and the error will be gone.

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

Step 2: Remove scope from pom.xml file for cucumber-JUnit dependency.

Answer (score 1):

For me the same issue was resolved by deleting .m2/repository, restart IDEA with dependencies as follows:

```
${cucumber.version} = 4.8.0

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope, it works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.I just removed scope part from the cucumber-junit dependency and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the  test  tag and it worked.

```
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I am using a Maven project in Eclipse. My problem seemed to be the JRE version I was using. My Maven projects all had an old J2SE-1.5 I switched to 1.8 within Eclipse and the issue went away. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, adding the below dependency resolved my issue:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded all the latest jar maven dependencies from "mvnrepository". This worked for me.

Comment: Did it fix this particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this dependency  and remove old one.
it worked for me.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you might have **cucumber-junit** in **pom.xml**

Confirm that under **Maven Dependencies** you must have **cucumber-junit**

[image]

I had 1.2.6 but it was not under Maven dependencies, Got this from one the comments in the answer.

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.5</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

To:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

It Worked...
```

**My Dependencies list:**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -3):

I have faced the same issue. Tried multiple things but what helped me is this 
`import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;`